# Ideal as an intersection of larger ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I = (x(z-1),x^2-yz)$. I'm asked to prove that $I = (x,x^2-yz)\bigcap(z-1,x^2-yz)$. I was able to prove that $I$ is contained in this intersection, but couldn't figure out the other one: I could only show that if $f \in (x,x^2-yz)\bigcap(z-1,x^2-yz)$ then $f^2 \in I$.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you prove $(x)\cap(z-1)\subseteq(x(z-1))$?

Comment: It makes more sense to say that "$I$ is an intersection of larger ideals" than to say that "$I$ is an intersection of smaller ideals". So, please replace the word "smaller" in the title with "larger".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, my issue is that if I write _f_ as a generic element of $(x,x^2-yz)$ and $(z-1,x^2-yz)$, the element multiplying $x^2-yz$ might not be the same

Answer (score 1):

Since you've already shown that $f^2\in I$, perhaps you can show $I$ is a radical ideal. This makes sense since both $(x,yz)$ and $(z-1,x^2-yz)$ are radical, since the quotients are $k[y,z]/(yz)$ and $k[y]$, respectively.

Begin with the set of generators $\{xz-x,yz-x^2\}$.

Consider the order on monomials on $k[x,y,z]$ given as follows. Order them lexicographically according to $z>y>x$. The leading term to the left is $xz$ and that to the right is $zy$.

The $S$-polynomial of the only overlap $xyz$ is $yx-x^3$, which you must append to get a Groebner basis. The rules are now

$$xz\to x,\quad yz\to x^2,\quad xy\to x^3.$$

I haven't been able to finish the argument, but with these rewriting system the problem disappears. For example, $(y+z)^2$ reduces to $y^2+z^2+2x^2$, which is also irreducible. Perhaps you can work out the details?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the last part of your argument. I understand that the reduction modulo _G_ must have the property that none of its monic terms is divisible by any of the leading terms, but a reduction with this property should be of the form $p + q$, with $p \in k[y]$, $q \in k[z]$, but the powers of the reduction might have a term divisible by $yz$ (for example $(y+z)^2=y^2+2yz+z^2$). How can one assure something like this doesn't happen?

Comment: @Mark There was a mistake in my reasoning, since the rewriting rules given by the Groebner basis were not terminating!  I'll rewrite my argument.